# refreshing java, relation between 2 interfaces not in heredity

Tags: java

I am refreshing my memory with java with self study but sometimes I got stuck with explanation till a point I ask myself - do I have to memorize this?

Below is an example of such:

I have the following :

```
    HashMap t= new HashMap();//class derived from Map Interface
```

How can we tell that `Set` interface reference can be derived from HashMap by doing :

```
    Set s=t.keySet();
```

1. Do we have to memorize the relations between interfaces and classes?
   I know the relation exists in JDK if we skim through dozens of methods but for someone who don't know all the existing methods, what should I do?
   In heredity relationship the relation is more obvious where to look for the relationship.
2. Note that SET and MAP are not in heredity relationship, so what we call this terminology to get a reference of an interface from a class method that exists in a separate and not related interface?
   example:

```
    Set s=t.keySet();
```

Comment: Use a good IDE, and you can see this information when writing your code (and the IDE can/will even auto-complete/generate it for you.

Comment: To use Java(in a professional environnement) or any other programming language you should know the basics of this language. those classes and interfaces , methods.. are your tools to do the work so you need to take a look (read a book for example ..)

Comment: Oussama ZAGHDOUD I know the basics and I am doing a refreshment now. i may not know everything but I am putting an effort ; I am also taking notes. Some topics like generics will get a headache if you dive deep, the question could be how deep should you dive to have the necessary functional knowledge.

Answer (score 3):

Basically, yes, in order to use a library - including the standard library - effectively, you need to learn what it contains. You can do this by reading the documentation, from tutorials, etc.

See for example the JavaDocs of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html) After a while, you remember what methods exist, at least well enough to be able to quickly look it up.

Usually, you don't need all that many classes in day-to-day business - `String`, `List`, `Map`, `Set`, the [`Stream` API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), `Optional`, and an occasional `Comparator` or the [`java.time`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) classes for date and time calculations. Use cases for all others are several orders of magnitude rarer, at least in my current projects.

That said, you don't usually think "I've got a map, I need a set, how do I convert this?" - because this, by itself, is not meaningful. Instead, you usually face a problem like "I need to print all keys in this map, how do I get them?" and you look at the methods of the `Map`-interface and find the appropriate one.

Comment: Thanks Hulk, any java utility that let you input 2 objects(classes and/or interfaces) and map possible relationship between them corresponding to the return methods?

Comment: None that I know of, no - and it wouldn't be very useful, either. Because more important than the information that the return type is `Set` is the information **which** elements the returned set contains, and that information is only available from documentation.

Comment: Note that a good IDE already will suggest a much smaller set of methods when you type `Set<T> keys = t.` (which is why many don't like the `var` keyword all that much). And yes, because of its slightly broken type system and heritage, a more modern language could remove quite a lot of methods from classes.